# How to access the WP REST-API from any javascript file enqueued on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

How to access the WP REST-API directly to read and write any public/private data from any javascript file enqueued in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

The NODE-WPAPI Client Authentication and Global Handle provides an easy hassle-free answer to this problem.

Check out: https://somefunagba.github.io/node-wpapi-auth/

- Go to Plugins Dashboard. Activate ‘NODE-WPAPI JS-CLIENT Install and Authentication’
- The Plugin is now activated, under it are the links: 
     Settings | Deactivate | Edit
- Click on this Settings link
- Enter any Administrator username and password, to validate Basic Authentication.
- Go to your live production or development site.
- Check your browser console: If your administrator’s name is Matt, then you should see a console output:

  ```
  “Matt! I am set to access the WP REST-API!”
  ```

**You are all set!**

> Open any .js script, enqueue it in Wordpress and start accessing the WORDPRESS REST-API using the WPAPI's, wp object directly.

```
    e.g : To get all the posts on your wordpress model site.
```

> Example: In something like a 'get_wp_post.js' script in your theme directory. Just insert this code snippets directly.

```
    wp.posts().embed().get().then(function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
        //do something with returned data
        });
```

> See http://wp-api.org/node-wpapi/ more info. on using the client to interact with WP REST-API.

N.B:

> Looking for your Browser Console? It should be something like:

- Mozilla Browser Console: Tools > Web Developer > Web Console
- Chrome Browser Console: More Tools > Dveloper Tools > Console